# C++ Linking command

Tags: c++, assembly, compilation, linker, compiler-construction

I'm currently trying to make a basic compiler on Windows using C++. And I was thinking about how to turn assembly into machine code or an exe file. If this were to be downloaded by another computer I think it wouldn't work without having to attach an assembler and linker with it, like nasm and ld. Is there any way at all to make this work without sending an assembler and linker?

Comment: My recommendation is to publish your compiler with an open source license. I certainly won't trust a compiler which is not open source (and yes, I did read papers about trusting compilers, which shows that even an open source compiler can be compromized). BTW, you could generate *directly* machine code with [ASMJIT](http://asmjit.com/) or use [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or generate C Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every compiler package I have ever used always includes an assembler and linker.

Most modern compilers don't use the assembler directly.  The same program converts C or another high level language directly into object code.

They do generally do the linking stage separately.  This can be with a different program, but the two programs are installed together as a package and most users don't concern themselves with which task is carried out by which part.

Comment: PS: an assembler is a lot simpler than a C++ compiler.  If you are really able to undertake to write your own C++ compiler, you should also be able to write your own assembler too.

Comment: True, but you might as well use an existing assembler, like LLVM is portable and is even compatible with non-GPL licences.  Also note that one of the major C compilers (GCC) *does* still compile to actual asm text files as part of going from C -> object file ([Does a compiler always produce an assembly code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14039843)).  And it's more common for less major compilers to just go to asm text instead of object files, because that factors out object-file format handling as well as machine-code.  Making a simple assembler is fairly easy; making a *nice* assembler is more work.

Comment: Wait, you can write an assembler?